# How to AddComponent(variable) easy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity 5.6

I need use something like `AddComponent(variable)`.

For example:

> I have empty scene.
>
> I have `List<string>` called `cpList` that contains the names of components.

Now I need something like this:

```
oj = new GameObject;
forEach(var cp in cpList ) {
    oj.addComponent(cp);
}
```

But I can't do that, because `AddComponent(string)` is deprecated.

Comment: so? is there any problem?

Comment: Yes. Problem is addComponent(string) deprecated\obsolete in Unity5.6.

Comment: What is your exact usecase? Why do you need this?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit. Are you trying to instantiate a gameobject?

Comment: I need reconstruct gameobject from scratch by using only string names. It was possible easy in old Unity but now not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
oj.addComponent(Type.GetType(cp));
```

Maybe you just need to get the Type of the component

Comment: It don't work for me.
For example Type.GetType("RigidBody") return null.

Comment: Well, it should be `"Rigidbody"` right?

Answer (score 0):

I would very much like to know what is your usecase here?

You can something like [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype) using the full reference name like e.g. `"UnityEngine.Rigidbody"` but I'm not sure if this is what you would really want to do

```
var obj =  new GameObject();
foreach (var cp in cpList)
{
    // Maybe try full names like e.g. "UnityEngine.Rigidbody"
    obj.AddComponent(Type.GetType(cp));
}
```

this is very error prone and not very efficient.

Alternatively also using Reflection and `Assembly.GetType` but then you need to know at least one type in the same assembly:

```
Assembly asm = typeof(UnityEngine.Object).Assembly;
Type type = asm.GetType("UnityEngine.Rigidbody");
```

---

You could rather use some hardcoded dictionary like e.g.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, Type> componentTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>()
{
    // some examples
    {"Camera", typeof(Camera)},
    {"SomeOtherScript", typeof(SomeOtherScript)}
}
```

and then do something like

```
var obj =  new GameObject();
foreach (var cp in cpList)
{
    if(!componentTypes.ContainsKey(cp))
    {
        Debug.LogError($"For the name {cp} no type was defined!");
    }
    obj.AddComponent(componentTypes[cp]);
}
```

Same could be done also with a simple `switch - case`.

Trade-off ofcourse you need one line/entry for each component you are going to tackle.

---

*Note: Typed on Smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: First method don't work.
I'm testing it in debug mode and:
var  =  Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("Rigidbody");
return Null.

Second method suggests\conduct me to know\enumerate all Unity3d components before using so it isn't good for me.

Comment: Maybe try the full name `UnityEngine.Rigidbody` . Also in this case you should rather use `Type.GetType` since the first example assumed you are talking about custom components which probably are built into another assembly as Unity built-in ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for this approach if you are looking for a quick fix:

```
foreach (var cp in cpList)
{
    if(cp.Equals("Text"))
        ob.AddComponent(Text);
    else if(cp.Equals("Rigidbody"))
        ob.AddComponent(Rigidbody);
    //Add more here
}
```

Compared to the other examples, this requires a lot more work, and is somewhat prone to type errors.

Edit: You may also have to handle the cases where you can't add two ui components.